# Difference between Open Connect Id implicit and hybrid flows

Tags: openid-connect

I have trouble understanding the differences of the implicit and hybrid flows of the OpenId Connect protocol.

Can someone please highlight the practical and security differences of each flow?
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implicit flow delivers tokens in the front channel i.e, via the browser, the hybrid flows deliver some tokens in the front channel and some in the back channel using direct HTTPs calls from client to Provider.

The back channel is generallly considered to be more secure since it does not expose tokens to HTTP logs, browser caches etc.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Which are the use cases for each flow?

Comment: implicit flow is typically for in-browser (Javascript) clients that can't keep a secret, hybrid is typically for clients that have their functionality distributed across a Javascript part and a server-side part